# how to test mobile touch event functions on a browser which is installed on my PC?

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, touch

how can I test the touch event functions I have programmed? I am programming all this on my persona computer. I do not have money to buy a phone with which I can touch the screen and test the touch event functions I programmed.

Please tell me if there is a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the Chrome DevTools and turn on the device-mode.
For reference
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/

Moreover, the link below describe the touch event on mobile, which is different from the click and mouseover event.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent

Answer (score 1):

one way that works on most (any?) browser is to use hammerjs touchemulator in your code

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/hammerjs/touchemulator/master/touch-emulator.js"></script>
```